# Is it worth it to use Bullet for 2D physics instead of Box2D for the sake of learning Bullet?

Tags: c++, physics, box2d, bullet-physics

There isn't much more to the question. I'm not concerned about overhead, as I'm sure they are both fine for my purposes. Basically, I am familiar with Box2D concepts because of the Farseer Physics Engine, but I want to use Bullet when I make the jump to 3D stuff. Perhaps Bullet has some educational value for me even in the 2D realm?

The generalized version of the question is: should I use a 3D physics engine for a 2D game if I plan to utilize a 3D physics engine in the future? Or is this a waste of time which would not provide educational value?

Comment: I think this question hinges heavily on how much the "sake of learning Bullet" is important to *you*.

Comment: The generalized version of the question is: should I use a 3D physics engine for a 2D game for educational value and potential future usefulness? As stated, I am planning on utilizing a 3D physics engine in future projects.

Comment: It isn't that much of a jump from engine X to engine Y, just how things are done are slightly different.

Comment: There is an official Bullet 2D example at: https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/2.83/examples/Planar2D/Planar2D.cpp It is classified under "Experiments" in the example browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not treat them separately?

You have a 2D game; use the right engine/tools to make that game the best it can be.

You want to mess around with a 3D engine to learn it; then mess around with it, make some simple 3D games or apps, but keep that separate from the other game you're working on.

Answer (score 17):

My generally feeling is always that learning to use something in the wrong context is not a valuable exercise.

Comment: can't agree more, you grab something always for some purpose. learning for future use sounds academic not practical